# spring batch using ClassifierCompositeItemwriter and additionally write all items to database

Tags: spring-batch

I have a project in spring batch, in which I read from a txt file (input data) and according to a validation of the item I read, it should be written in a txt file (output 1) or in another txt file (output 2) I think for this i should use a ClassifierCompositeItemwriter, how i can do to additionally write all items that I read in a database (output 3)?
I must keep in mind that the three outputs have different formats

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CompositeItemWriter` which will delegate writing to a list of `ItemWriter` . The order of the `ItemWriter` list is important as it will call the `ItemWriter` in order. So make sure `ClassifierCompositeItemwriter` is before the `ItemWriter` for writing to database. :

```java
@Bean
public ItemWriter itemWriter(ClassifierCompositeItemwriter classiferWriter ,JdbcBatchItemWriter jdbcWriter){
  CompositeItemWriter writer = new CompositeItemWriter();
  writer.setDelegates(List.of(classiferWriter,jdbcWriter));
  return writer;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I wasn't thinking of using ClassifierCompositeItemWriter in conjunction with CompositeItemWriter as an option